# Stars more affected by gravity of stars further away, need help understanding argument why

Tags: newtonian-gravity, galaxies

In the first chapter of Binney and Tremaine's "Galactic Dynamics" there is a statement that I don't yet understand. The first chapter of the book is [linked here, straight from the publisher](http://press.princeton.edu/chapters/s8697.pdf).  The statement is in the second paragraph of section 1.2, which begins on PDF page 34 (print page 33).

The argument is that, in a galaxy, a star is more affected by the gravitational force from stars further away than stars closer by.  Since force is proportional to $r^{-2}$, and (assuming uniform density) the number of stars seen by an observer at a radius $r$ in a given angle is proportional to $r^2$.  However, there is an extra factor of $r$ that comes in (the radius of each "octave", as they've defined octave) and I am not sure the physical reason why this $r$ comes in.  With this extra $r$, the gravitational force is proportional to $r^{-2} \times r^2 \times r = r$.

What is the physical reason for that extra factor of $r$?  Why does the length of the octave come in?

Answer (score 2):

That's a very confusing paragraph.  They use the term 'octave' specifically for a doubling of distance (r) --- that's not important.  The argument is simply that the force *per star* falls off as $r^{-2}$, but the number of stars actually increases as $r^3$.  So as you increase distance, the gravity increases by $r$.

We could write this more precisely as for a constant number density of stars $n$,
$$F \propto \int n \frac{1}{r^2} dV = \int n \frac{1}{r^2} r^2 dr \propto r$$

Comment: That last step only makes sense if you integrate from $0$ to $r$.  But we're integrating over similar sized shells (at least same size in radius) at different radii.  If the shell size is $\Delta r$, then the integral gives a value of $\Delta r$ for every shell, independent of its radius.  At least that's how I understand it.

Comment: @Joshua, yes - you're right, its just whatever with `dr` you look at.  but that's why they specified an 'octave' --- i.e. a length proportional to `r` (in this case `2r`).  As long as that's true, this proportionality holds.   In astro, since most things are power-laws, you assume that variations are on the order of the initial values, i.e. $\delta x \sim x$.

Comment: I'm still having a difficult time understanding.  What are so magical about octaves that it's okay that they give a different result than the one I mention with $\Delta r$?

Comment: @Joshua they don't give a conflicting result.  The import thing is that the force scales roughly linearly with distance, it doesn't matter if that's $r$ or $\Delta r$.  I was trying to additional point out, that if the integral bounds are something like $\alpha r$ to $\beta r$ (for some constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$) then the specific form of the result $F \propto r$ holds.  This is an order of magnitude type argument.